# Windows 10 in UEFI mode and Ubuntu in Legacy mode

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

My laptop have already installed Windows 10 in UEFI but I mistakenly dual boot Ubuntu OS In legacy mode.
So everytime I have to change BIOS SETUP settings to UEFI for Windows and legacy and legacy first for Ubuntu. So what I do to when I start my pc it ask me which OS to use(it also ask currently but don't run the other one according to BIOS setting)

Comment: What is your question? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: it's easy to find out how to [convert Ubuntu to UEFI mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Converting_Ubuntu_into_UEFI_mode) if you paste that to Google and search

Answer (score 0):

The switch from legacy boot to UEFI boot in Ubuntu should be fairly easy, only a few steps are needed.

First of all make sure that Windows is fully shut down, Windows `Fast-startup`-feature should be disabled. Boot your current Ubuntu installation.

You need to know which partition is your EFI-System-Partition (ESP). You can use the command `lsblk -f` to get the device name and UUID of the ESP. The ESP is formatted in FAT and normally has a size of a few hundred MB, mostly the partition will be labeled and you can find it easily.

Create a directory as mount-point for the ESP with

```
sudo mkdir /boot/efi
```

Now add a line to /etc/fstab with the following content:

```
UUID=XXXXXXXXX   /boot/efi  vfat   umask=0077    0    1
```

Use the UUID you found before.

Mount the ESP with `sudo mount-a`

Now install the `grub-efi-amd64`-package:

```
sudo apt install grub-efi-amd64
```

This will automatically remove `grub-pc` (the legacy boot-mode version of Grub).

Other commands like `grub-install or update-grub` are not needed, installing `grub-efi-amd64` will install the boot-loader to the ESP during installation of the package.You are ready to reboot.

Enter the UEFI-settings and check your boot-order. I'd also recommend to disable CSM in UEFI-settings to speed up the boot process.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, I've successfully converted my legacy install to efi this way.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to reinstall Ubuntu in UEFI mode cause moving from legacy to UEFI not so simple. You should:

- Boot from Live-USB;
- Create FAT32 partition (minimum 33MB of size) and mark it with boot flag;
- Enter chroot mode by:

  - `sudo mount -o /dev/sdxX /mnt` where xX is you drive and partition number where a root partition is;
  - `sudo mount /dev/sdxX /mnt/boot/efi`
  - `for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /run /sys; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done`
  - `sudo chroot /mnt`
  - `for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /run /sys; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done`
  - `sudo chroot /mnt`

Now install grub:

```
apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64
grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX
```

or just:

```
dpkg-reconfigure grub-efi-amd64
```

It should create 'ubuntu' menu item in UEFI.

Now edit your fstab by `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and add the following to it:

```
UUID=bla-bla  /boot/efi  vfat  umask=0077 0  1
```

You should run `blkid` to identify which UUID your efi partition has.

Check which packages are installed by `dpkg --get-selections | grep grub`

```
grub-common                                     install
grub-efi                                        install
grub-efi-amd64                                  install
grub-efi-amd64-bin                              install
grub2-common                                    install
```

Those are packages should be installed for UEFI boot. All other you should remove.

Also check that `/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` file is exist.

Exit from chroot by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.
Unmount all in `/mnt` and try to reboot.