# how to replace /boot by /boot/efi for dual boot system

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I have a multiple hard drive setup with Ubuntu-18.04 as a primary OS (for some accident installed in legacy/BIOS mode, first Linux experience). Recently I added an extra SSD and installed win10 on it. Somehow I managed to get things to work, but the problem is that win10 boot in UEFI while ubuntu in legacy/BIOS mode. As I am new to ubuntu, I figured out the legacy type of install only after I tried to boot-repair in UEFI and broke my working grub (luckily I managed to restore it). I don't want to break things again, so I have a few questions:

1. Is it safe/ok to dual boot legacy ubuntu and UEFI windows by simply switching the boot order directly in "bios" firmware? (I am ok with doing that, but maybe I should avoid this practice?)
2. How can I convert my ubuntu 18.04 to UEFI mode without breaking anything to enable normal dual boot setup?

Regarding the second question, yes I read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI, but it didn't help much since it does not provide a ready-to-use solution. With my level of understanding of how boot works I came up with the following idea to fix my setup:

0. I have several disks `/dev/nvme0n1` for windows, /`dev/nvme1n1` for linux and some `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb` for storage. Linux partitions are `/dev/nvme1n1p1=/boot`, `/dev/nvme1n1p2=/`, `/dev/nvme1n1p3=swap`, `/dev/nvme1n1p4=/home`. (`/boot` is large enough)
1. Boot in currently installed legacy ubuntu 18.04, use GParted to unmount `/boot`, erase it, make new fat32 (vfat) partition on the same place and remount it to `/boot/efi` (also add a corresponding record in `/etc/fstab`).
2. Reboot and boot to boot-repair disk (https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) in UEFI mode and *click* recommended fix.
3. Reboot to **uefi ubuntu**, run `$>sudo update-grub`? *Done*?

But I decided not to go for it as I am afraid that something *will* go wrong and I will end up with an entirely failed system. (It was really scary to enter grub-rescue> or grub> and when it failed to load after specifying correct boot and root folders...) Or maybe there is a simpler and more clear way (e.g. do the boot repair in current running ubuntu, then just reboot).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’d say your best bet is to reinstall Ubuntu in UEFI mode. Backup your /home before doing that and restore it after. Backup anything else on the machine that you cannot afford to lose

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1073683/590937

Comment: @PonJar, can i make the backup on second hard drive (physically installed) rather than on second machine?

Comment: @mook765, that looks like exactly what i want to do, but i dont have /boot/efi partition yet, just /boot. So can i unmount and erase the /boot partition (and remove the corresponding folder), then create fat32 boot partition on the freed space and mount it on /boot/efi to proceed your solution?

Comment: What is mounted at `/boot/efi` is the EFI System Partition (ESP). You should have an ESP since you have Windows installed in EFI-mode. **Do not delete** your `/boot`-partition, this would make Ubuntu unable to boot. Instead, find out the correct partition, create the folder `/boot/efi`, mount the ESP there and install the bootloader as described in the link.

Comment: It is also safe to change the boot-order in UEFI-firmware to switch between the operating systems during boot. Most people will find this inconvenient, but it's safe.

Comment: @mook765 tried you method, but no success, still loads to /boot (legacy). Maybe i messed with some commands, maybe something else, maybe grub should be removed first. (Though nothing seems to be broken after all.)

Comment: The old bootloader (grub) still resides in MBR. Try to disable legacy boot in firmware settings, check boot-order, save and exit from firmware-settings and see if it works.

Comment: Make also sure that secure boot is disabled in firmware-settings.

Comment: You should place you backup in a safe place. The Windows drive should be safe but to be sure sounds like you could disconnect it while reinstalling Ubuntu in UEFI mode. That should make for a very easy install, just update grub after the Windows disk is reconnected to get a Windows entry on the grub menu.