# Cannot resize old ubuntu installed drive, is bios_grub partition safe to delete?

Tags: gparted, drive

So I dual boot installed Ubuntu even though it is not dual boot (I cannot choose), apparently the second install is a mistake, so I wanna resize it but I can't, please help I did not know what to do

- So how do I delete it in live Ubuntu?
- Does deleting the grub_bios partition risky?
- Do I have to clone Ubuntu then delete these 2 drives
- Do I have to get fresh installation which is a lot to prepare for my programming needs,
- Do I have another suggestion, please?
  Thank you

This is my drive from GParted software

[image: img_GParted]

Comment: Yes you can do it in *live*, grub is installed in the `/boot/grub` directory so I'm not sure what you mean by "*grub_bios*" partition, MBR refers to the first 512 bytes of the disk which is outside of partition(s) being device specific (ie. relates to `sda` which is the device,where as `sda1` for example is a partition). You don't need to re-install or clone, but I could be missing something as your post is a little unclear (to me anyway)

Comment: @guiverc ive posted the image link, i dont know how to make them visible, the sda 8 is grub_bios partition so i kinda wonder is it safe to delete it or not

so i boot live ubuntu, then install gparted, and then delete sda7,sda8,and sda9 and sda10? then i merged it to sda 4?
sorry i have to admid it, im kinda dumb, i hope u can help me here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bios_grub` is onlyd needed when you want to install Ubuntu in legacy mode on a disk with GPT partition table.

Your disk obviously has a GPT partition table. Since Windows boot mode is bound to the partition table type (GPT>UEFI-mode, msdos>legacy-mode), your Windows is installed in UEFI-mode.

To achieve a proper dual-boot, you have to install Ubuntu in the same boot-mode as Windows (also Windows fast-startup feature must be turned off), thus you have to install Ubuntu in UEFI-mode. In UEFI-mode, the `bios_grub`-partition is not needed and you could delete it before you reinstall.

I'd recommend to disable legacy boot (sometimes called CSM) in your UEFI/Bios-settings, so you can't boot in the wrong boot-mode accidentally, how you boot is how you install.

I converted my legacy install into an UEFI install a few years ago without reinstalling the OS, [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1073683/590937) is how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a live Ubuntu.

Deleting the grub_bios partition is risky, don't do this when your PC has no UEFI-BIOS but only an "old" BIOS. I suggest, just don't touch that partition, even when you have an UEFI-BIOS.

You don't need to clone, but making backups is always a good idea, when possible.

A fresh installation would be best.

---

#### What you can do to delete the old Ubuntu is:

- boot your regular Ubuntu, the one you want to keep
- open a terminal and type `sudo -i` and hit *ENTER*, this gives you root rights
- make a backup of your *fstab* by typing `cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak`  and hit *ENTER*
- edit *fstab* by typing `nano /etc/fstab` and hitting *ENTER*

  - find the unwanted partitions within the fstab config and delete their entries
  - press *CTRL+O* for saving the changes to file
  - press *CTRL+X* for quitting the editor
- reboot your system (the same system)
- open another terminal and give you again root rights by typing `sudo -i` and hitting *ENTER*
- type `parted` into terminal and hit *ENTER*, this starts the partition manager

  - **be very careful when using *parted***, it's an interactive program, **all changes are instant!**
  - type *`help`* and hit *ENTER* to get a command help list
  - type *`print devices`* and hit *ENTER* to see all storage devices
  - search for the storage device (probably harddisk /dev/sda) you want to change
  - type *`select /dev/sda`* and hit *ENTER* to select your desired storage device
  - type *`print free`* and hit *ENTER* to display partitions of your selected storage device
  - **CAREFULLY!**  type *`rm NUMBER`*, where NUMBER is the number of the partition you want to delete and hit *ENTER* - (double check your typing!)
  - type *`print free`* and hit *ENTER* to verify your changes
  - **OPTIONAL:** type *`resizepart`* and hit *ENTER* to adjust partition size of the remaining partitions, make sure to only increase the size of your partitions, **don't decrease the size of your partitions!** You can only resize partitions which are not mounted, so maybe a live Ubuntu would do better here.
  - type *`quit`* and hit *ENTER* to quit *parted*
- type `update-grub` in terminal and hit *ENTER* (this updates the boot menu)
- reboot your system